# Use curved surface filling

Tags: python

I am new to Blender 3d
i want to fill the bottom surface to make it closed
[image]

The effect of shortcut key k is not very good
[image]

[image]

So I want to know if there is a way to achieve perfection

grid fill works but the effect is not very good
It has too many protrusions, and I hope the surface to be repaired is an approximate plane

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Achieving "perfection" in a situation like this is not possible. Because whatever algorithm is used to fill the areas cannot know what shape the object has in the real world or what your idea of what it should look like is. There are certainly a few "best fit" methods, but it will be best if you make it clear what conditions you place on a perfect filling (e.g. maintaining the lower edge contour). A simple solution would be to scale the lower edges along the z-axis to 0 and move them along the z-axis so that they do not overlap with the other geometry and then fill them.

Comment: @a-python-script Yes, I hope to maintain the contour of the lower edge. My perfect meaning is to fill it with a more natural curved surface rather than just a simple plane.This is a model of earphones，and face need to fill is the outside

Comment: @moonboots I'm so sorry that i cant't provide the model.You can create a cube, subdivide it, select a circle of vertices and the vertices below it, and then delete the faces to simulate it

Comment: Have you tried using `Grid Fill`?

Comment: I doubt anyone could use it for anything, you could just modify it a bit before sharing  ;)

Comment: @a-python-script o,thank you,I try Grid Fill just now,it works,but the the effect is not very good as i show